# Transform array of elements into an array of reference_wrappered elements

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I have an array of some elements.
I would like to create a function that will generate an array of reference_wrapper containing the references of the element.

Something that will have an interface like:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
std::array<std::reference_wrapper<T>,N> wrap(std::array<T,N>& a);
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Note: I don't want to use vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this. Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/2MbiY5).

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Index>
    std::array<std::reference_wrapper<T>, N> wrap(std::array<T, N>& a,
                                                  std::index_sequence<Index...>) {
        return {a[Index]...};
    }
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
std::array<std::reference_wrapper<T>,N> wrap(std::array<T,N>& a) {
    return detail::wrap(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Comment: I knew, it  should have been some c++magic to do it at compile time. Thanks!